# Adding jpg to a pdf, using fpdf

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg, fpdf

I am creating a jpg in my python program, and would like to make it part of a pdf with fpdf. Is that possible without writing it to a file first?

Comment: fpdf does not support importing images directly from variables but can export to variable if you pass `S` instead of `F` when calling `pdf.output`:  `scan_pdf = pdf.output("scannedDocuemnt", "S")`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. In the [fpdf image](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html) docs, it says for the `name` param in adding an image with `fpdf.image(name, x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')`:

```
name: 
 
     Path or URL of the image.
```

This implies that you're not passing an object representing an image directly in as the parameter, but only the path to an image that is already saved to disk as a file. This is so when you call something like `pdf.output('tuto1.pdf', 'F')`, it will build the PDF at that point from the text, images, etc.